# All combinations for 'x' and 'y'

Tags: postgresql

Give all the possible combinations for 'x' and 'y' (the letters, not column x or column y). It should return one column with results:
xx
xy
yx
yy

Thanks

Comment: `values ('xx'),('xy'),('yx'), ('yy');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for a cross join, which returns the Cartesian product of two tables. Here I'm using a common table expression and two aliases instead of creating two tables.

```
with values as (
  select 'x' val union all
  select 'y'
)
select v1.val || v2.val combin 
from values v1
cross join values v2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure understanding your intent perfectly, but perhaps the following would be close to what you want:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
select x||y 
from (select 'x'::text as x union select 'y'::text as x) x
cross join (select 'y'::text as y union select 'x'::text as y) y
```

Regards